# make selected text visible in PGAdmin 4 Query Editor

Tags: postgresql, colors, highlight, pgadmin

Here the pg_available_extensions word is selected:

[image]

The selection is not visible

I tried to find a configuration parameter that would address this issue and could not find one. I lost hours trying to fix this as there are behavior associated to selected text that I use all the time. This issue makes the whole application unusable to me.

The following image has the word configuration selected with a blue background:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y9ed.png)

Comment: The selected identifier is easily visible to me in that image. Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: If you truly can't see the selected text, it could be a monitor/graphical card or eye issue.

Comment: I assume it is `Apache AGE` you are looking for not the native Postgres `age` function. It is an extension and I do not believe one of the automatically supplied ones. You can download it from [https://age.apache.org](https://age.apache.org).

Comment: Tks for commenting. When I d-click any word on this page, the text immediately acquires a blue background (suggesting that eye issue is out of the way). I don't have that behavior in pgAdmin 4 query editor. Do you see a blue background color?

Comment: You are right, I try to run a graph database on postgres in wsl2 window11. I read the instruction on github and they are at best inconsistent and bad. As though the product is emptied out of its usefulness just about ready to be commercialized. What are the components? Is AGE a whole gdbms and postgres makes a connection to it?

Comment: My goal is to avoid installing a graph engine and to try to build GNN with the graph db using only postgres. Who wants to manage a gdbms and rdbms? That sounds like too much red tape to have access to GNNs.